# I would like know the attribute html of an element in Elm

Tags: html, styles, elm

I would like know the attribute html of an element in Elm, for example, her coordinates. I were trying with Json.Decode.

I am new in Elm, and this is for learning purpose.

**This is a simple code, i am using Elm 0.18:**

```elm
module Stamps exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)


type alias Model =
    {}


type Msg
    = NoOp
    | Clicking


model : Model
model =
    {}


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NoOp ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        Clicking ->
            let
                _ =
                    Debug.log "msg1" model
            in
                ( model, Cmd.none )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div
        [ Html.Attributes.style
            [ ( "backgroundColor", "blue" )
            , ( "height", "300px" )
            , ( "width", "300px" )
            , ( "position", "relative" )
            , ( "left", "100px" )
            , ( "top", "50px" )
            ]
        , Html.Attributes.class
            "parent"
        ]
        [ div
            [ Html.Attributes.style
                [ ( "background-color", "#3C8D2F" )
                , ( "cursor", "move" )
                , ( "width", "100px" )
                , ( "height", "100px" )
                , ( "border-radius", "4px" )
                , ( "position", "absolute" )
                , ( "color", "white" )
                , ( "display", "flex" )
                , ( "align-items", "center" )
                , ( "justify-content", "center" )
                ]
            , Html.Attributes.class
                "children"
            , Html.Events.onClick Clicking
            ]
            []
        ]


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( model, Cmd.none )
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

So I'm not really sure which of the offsets you're trying to get specifically, but I think this will put you on track. First you need to adjust your Msg ADT's Clicking to have a tuple for the coordinates.

```
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | Clicking Int Int
```

Assuming you want to stick with just logging the coords for now, you can use this. DO remember that you can destructure in the pattern match if you need.

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NoOp ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        Clicking x y ->
            let
                _ =
                    Debug.log "coords" ( x, y )
            in
                ( model, Cmd.none )
```

You need a `Json.Decode.Decoder` to that tuple.

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)


coordsDecoder : (Int -> Int -> a) -> Decoder a
coordsDecoder into =
    Decode.field "target" <| 
        Decode.map2 into
            (Decode.field "offsetWidth" Decode.int)
            (Decode.field "offsetHeight" Decode.int)
```

And lastly, you need the `on` to take decoder do something with the `Event` object returned by a JavaScript click event. This decoder gets the coordinates, then `Decode.map`s the `Clicking` msg type.

```
Html.Events.on "click" (coordsDecoder Clicking)
```

With that `Decode.field "target" ...` you can start decoding whatever you want from the target element.

---

Stylistically, you're importing all of the `Html.*` functions into scope with `exposing (..)`, but you're still prefixing everything which is pretty redundant. You can just use `style` instead of `Html.Attributes.style`. Don't be afraid to use `as` -> `Html.Attributes as Attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer, in case if i try to get the coordinates in relation to the browser, in case the style left and top are not definity. I am searching some solution and found this

```html
offsetParent : a -> Decoder a -> Decoder a
offsetParent x decoder =
  Decode.oneOf
    [ field "offsetParent" <| Decode.null x
    , field "offsetParent" decoder
    ]
```